# How to use cmd command in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, cmd

I tried several ways found online, but have same exception below:

```
 Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Following is my build script:

```
files.each { File file ->
        if (file.isFile()) {
            println " *** $file.name ***"
            exec {
                commandLine "cmd", "/c", "native2ascii", "$file.name", "$file.name"
            }
        }
    }
println " ==== Encoding done === "
```

Comment: Are you using windows operating system ? What 'cmd' command do in windows? I know how gradle execute linux command. But not much idea about windows cmd prompt.

Comment: The native2ascii.exe command in JDK folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `exec` block as follows:

```
exec {
    commandLine "cmd", "/c native2ascii $file.name $file.name"
}
```

Comment: I changed to this and it compiles successfully: 
`commandLine "cmd", "native2ascii", "$file.name", "$file.name" + "tmp"
            commandLine "cmd", "del", "$file.name"
            commandLine "cmd", "move", "$file.name" + "tmp", "$file.name"`, 
but it didn't work,  the files are not changed.

Comment: The commands in the question and comment are different. Just want to make sure if you facing issues with the command in the question or comment?

Comment: The thumb rule is to make sure that all the stuff after `cmd` is wrapped in a pair of double quotes. No need to put each command in separate quotes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My first time using this, and I found it's used with separate quotes somewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to encode the file by native2ascii, but it didn't work when I used the same name like this: `native2ascii a a`, so I have to define another name in Gradle, like this: ` def tmpName = "$file.name" + "tmp"
            commandLine "cmd", "/c native2ascii $file.name $tmpName"`, the tmpName is printed correctly, but the new file with this name is not created. Can you help with  this?

Comment: I am not sure if it would work, could you remove `/c` and run it?

Comment: I removed the last `/c` and it works as bellows:
`commandLine "cmd", "/c native2ascii $file.name $tmpName"
            commandLine "cmd", "/c del $file.name"
            commandLine "cmd", "move $tmpName $file.name"` , but only the last file in the folder is changed as expected. Namely, encoded to ASCII file.

Comment: Could you please add the complete code as part of the question itself. It is easier to read.